# Bison/Flex creating list

Tags: c, bison

Im trying to convert from infix to postfix and capturing the char in the correct order using a list. Here is my bison file:

```
%{
    #include <stdio.h>
    #include <stdlib.h>
    #include <math.h>
    #include <string.h>
%}
%union{
    char list[100];
    int integer;
};

%token <integer> NUM
%token ENDOFLINE
%left '+' '-'
%left '*' '/'
%right NEGATIVE
%type <list> Exp
%%

Statement: 
    | Statement Line
;
Line: Exp ENDOFLINE{ printf("Result -> %s\n", $1);  }
    | ENDOFLINE
;
Exp:  Exp '+' Exp {add($$,(char)$2);}
    |   Exp '*' Exp {add($$,(char)$2);}
    |   Exp '-' Exp {add($$,(char)$2);}
    |   Exp '/' Exp {add($$,(char)$2);}
    |   '-' Exp %prec NEGATIVE {add($$,(char) $1);}
    |   NUM     {$$ = create_list(); add($$,(char) $1);}
;
%%
char * create_list(){
    char expList [100];
    return expList;
}
void add(char* array, char input){
    int length = stlen(array);
    array[length] = input;
}
int main(){
    yyparse();

}

int yyerror (char *msg) {
    return printf ("error YACC: %s\n", msg);
}
```

I have multiple problems, one being that it says i cant add an int to char[], and another saying request for member add in something not a struct or union. I'm very new to Bison/Flex, is this the proper implementation if i want to store these values so i might use them in main(at some point)?

**EDIT**: Here is my most up to date code. I updated my lex file to recognize the individual operators and return that token as well as added the proper functions and their prototypes to my bison file(a4grammer2.y).

```
%{
    #include <stdio.h>
    #include <stdlib.h>
    #include <math.h>
    #include <string.h>

    char * create_list();
    void add(char* array, char input);
    int yyerror(char* s);
    int main(void);
%}
%union{
    char list[100];
    char character;
    int integer;
};

%token <integer> NUM
%token <character> PLUS
%token <character> MINUS
%token <character> MULTIPLY
%token <character> DIVIDE
%token ENDOFLINE
%right NEGATIVE
%type <list> Exp
%%

Statement: 
    | Statement Line
;
Line: Exp ENDOFLINE{ printf("Result -> %s\n", $1);  }
    | ENDOFLINE
;
Exp:  Exp PLUS Exp {add($$,$2);}
    |   Exp MULTIPLY Exp {add($$,$2);}
    |   Exp MINUS Exp {add($$,$2);}
    |   Exp DIVIDE Exp {add($$,$2);}
    |   MINUS Exp %prec NEGATIVE {add($$,$1);}
    |   NUM     {strcpy($$,create_list()); add($$, $1);}
;
%%
char * create_list(){
    char expList [100];
    return expList;
}
void add(char* array, char input){
    int length = stlen(array);
    array[length] = input +'0';
}
int main(){
    yyparse();

}

int yyerror (char *msg) {
    return printf ("error YACC: %s\n", msg);
}
```

now when i compile this using:

```
yacc -d a4grammer2.y
```

I get this error

```
warning: 20 shift/reduce conflicts [-Wconflicts-sr]
```

and when i try to compile using gcc i get this:

```
a4grammer2.y: In function ‘create_list’:
a4grammer2.y:44:5: warning: function returns address of local variable [-Wreturn-local-addr]
     return expList;
```

Comment: The value for `Exp` is an array of characters, meaning that in the `Exp` rules `$$` is also an array of characters. And you would not expect e.g. `list->add('+')` to work, would you? You need to actually create functions to append the characters to the array.

Comment: @JoachimPileborg i believe i added the proper function that i need. However when i try to pass the second parameter it tells me it has no type even when i try and cast it as a char

Comment: You need to add a prototype declaration of the function before you can call it, otherwise the compiler will not know it exits. Also, if you want to treat the array as a string, you need to remember to zero-terminate it properly. Lastly, please edit your question to show the *actual* and *complete* and *unedited* errors, because otherwise all we can do, really, is just guess.

Comment: @JoachimPileborg i edited in my most up to date code along with the full errors/warnings it is producing when i go to compile it.

Comment: You are returning a pointer to a local variable in the `create_list` function, and as you (should) know local variables go out of scope when a function returns, leaving you with a stray pointer. You don't even *need* that function, just do e.g. `strcpy($$, strtol($1, NULL, 10));`

Comment: @JoachimPileborg doesnt strtol return a long?

Comment: Oh yes you're correct, I can't seem to be thinking all straight today. You need to convert the integer to a string, some libraries have a non-standard `itoa` function or similar, but it's not hard to write such a functions.

Comment: @JoachimPileborg alright cool, so i got that working with sprintf. It compiles now. however when it reaches any of the add() function such as for the "+" i get this error: 'error YACC: syntax error'

Answer (score 0):

Apart from what has been noted in comments:

```
Exp:  Exp '+' Exp {add($$,(char)$2);}
```

This, and every production like it, should be of the general form

```
Exp:  Exp '+' Exp {$$ = add($1,$3);}
```

and I have no idea what makes you think that every `Exp` can be cast to a `char.` Life would be very uninteresting, and your program entirely unnecessary, if that were the case.

Comment: I dont want to add the first and third variables together. the add function is adding the operator to the array of characters.